# BufferedImage not getting the correct colors

Tags: java, image, colors, awt

So I am loading in a png image to resize it when I realised that the images color was changed slightly. I identified that this happened when I loaded the image with the following example.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("imagepath"));
final int rgb = image.getRGB(300, 300);
Color color = new Color(rgb);
System.out.println(color);
```

Inspecting the color i found that the RGB values for the pixel where:
java.awt.Color[r=238,g=28,b=35]

The image used is https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7HtT.jpg in which the color values for the red is 255,0,33

I am using jdk1.8.0_131 if that is of any interest.

Comment: Opening the image with GIMP causes a message to appear, saying that this image uses an "Embedded Color Profile", and allows either 1. keeping the profile or 2. converting it to sRGB. When converting it to sRGB, the color becomes (255,0,33). When keeping the profile, the color is (238,28,35). I just tried to convert the image at runtime, but that's a PITA. I'd **STRONGLY** recommend to simply open the image with GIMP and save it in a more common variant of PNG.

Comment: Ah that explains things, I will see what I can do with the color profile then. Thanks a lot!